# Is it possible to know how many shields are deployed to on a portal in ingress?

Tags: ingress

On the ingress intel map http://ingress.com/intel I can see how many shields are deployed on both friendly and enemy portals.

Is it possible to see how many shields and of which level are deployed to an enemy portal in ingress tactical - ingress app.

As far as I know I can only see whether the portal has a shield or not, but I cannot say how power is it, does anyone know a way to say except to consult to intel map.

Comment: Rumor is, there is intentionally an information asymmetry between the strategic and tactical page/app. Another case is that the tactical app tends to have a limited view range. The vision here being that you might have a strategic player at /intel providing info to agents on the ground via the faction chat.

Comment: @Adam I think it's designed so too, but people always find amazing workarounds. Maybe you can say how powerful the shield is by the animation frequency or color or something else, who knows :)

Comment: Yeah, like I found that if I use a key to bring up a portal, I can look around further than I could otherwise. Also, I've heard that the opacity of a field near a portal gives a hint to its rezs' health.

Answer (score 5):

Zoomed in you can see that a shield is there or not by it's glowing sphere animation around the column of the portal. I believe the color is more intense for a rarer shield. I am unable however to count the number of shields.

Comment: This answer should be updated as it is now possible to view the mods of an enemy portal simply by pulling up the portal in a scanner view and tapping on the mods section.